# Can I have two service outlets for two separate pieces of equipment on the same circuit?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, hot-tub

Location: Seattle, USA.

I've got an existing service outlet, on a dedicated circuit, for my heat pump compressor (exterior of my house).  I plan to add a hot tub (spa) in the near future, and this piece of equipment, too, requires a service outlet.  Unfortunately, the HVAC outlet is beyond 20' from the spa, so an additional outlet is required closer to the spa.  Is it acceptable to run this outlet from the HVAC service outlet - i.e. both outlets on the same circuit?  Or do I need the spa service outlet to be on a dedicated circuit?  My motivation for extending the HVAC circuit would simply be to save a breaker slot in my main panel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes they can share a circuit, there is no requirement that either of those service receptacles be on a dedicated circuit.

Neither Pool Section [680.22](https://up.codes/viewer/seattle/nfpa-70-2020/chapter/6/special-equipment#680.22) or Equipment Service [210.63](https://up.codes/viewer/seattle/nfpa-70-2020/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#210.63) receptacles specify "individual branch circuit" or contain the phrase "shall have no other outlets".

One possible clarification, if your tub is a light duty 120v plug-in model then [210.21(B)](https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#210.23_(B)) restrictions regarding 50%/80% of capacity of shared circuits or the manufacturers instructions will likely require a dedicated circuit for the spa, and the 680.22 wording "receptacle on a general-purpose branch circuit" would require separate circuits for the tub and service receptacles.

Comment: Presuming the circuit is wired to take the worst case load, of course

Answer (score 2):

### They're NOT service outlets!

It wastes money and totally defeats the purpose to treat these outlets as "service outlets" dedicated to that piece of equipment.

What Code is actually saying is that every HVAC maintainer's vacuum pump should have a 25 foot cord. And they should reasonably expect that every home has a **general-use outdoor outlet** within reach of that cord.

People wrongly assume this socket needs to be sacramental in some way. That makes no sense at all, since the typical lifespan of an outdoor GFCI receptacle is about 10 years, and A/C's typically need service far less often than that.  **That means a dedicated receptacle will be stone dead every time the maintainer tries to use it**, and the guy will have to trot out the 100' extension cord anyway, and you'll fix it the next day, only to fail again before next visit.  Which completely defeats the purpose.

No. What you want, and what the A/C guy would prefer, is a general-use receptacle intended for YOUR use for everything from hedge trimmers to bouncy castles to Christmas lights.  That way, when it fails, you fix it, and the A/C maintainer finds an outlet you used last month and does work.

Likewise the pool receptacle.

If you just don't have a reason for a general-use outdoor receptacle nearby, what's on the inside of the building there? Find a receptacle* on the inside of the wall, change it to GFCI, then come off its LOAD terminals and feed a plain receptacle outside within 25' of the air conditioner or pool.  That's it. You're done, and the GFCI is indoors where the weather won't wreck it.

* All kitchen and bathroom countertop receptacle circuits must be on circuits dedicated for that type or room.  However laundry and garage can have more than one circuit; only one of which must be a dedicated 20A circuit to that room. All receptacles not thusly dedicated are candidates.

Comment: Haterz gon' h8...

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many outlets as you want on a single circuit. However if the total current is higher than the conductor can handle it is going to burn - to prevent this, a circuit breaker or a fuse is used un the main panel. Remember, the purpose of the circuit breaker (fuse) is to protect the cable from melting.

Lastly a hot tub is reactively high power load, it would also need an extra GFCI protection.